# Algorithm not counting the size of images using mochiweb parser

Tags: erlang, mochiweb

I am trying to make this https://ppolv.wordpress.com/2008/05/09/fun-with-mochiwebs-html-parser-and-xpath/ algorithm work. So everything is compiling and working pretty good (I am getting the size of html page) but:

**What I expected:**

Size of html

Size of images

Size of scripts

**What I get:**

Size of html

Size of images equal to zero no matter what

Size of scripts equal to zero no matter what

I was trying to find the error  or something that I missed for hours but I have no idea what is wrong.
Code:

```
-module(test).
-author("Hubert").

%% API
-export([printing/4]).
-export([page_info/1]).
-export([got_page_info/3]).
-export([content_length/1]).
-export([spawn_workers/3]).
-export([get_info/2]).
-export([get_url_context/1]).
-export([wait_for_responses/2]).

%declaring record that will hold number of images, css and scripts
-record(state, {page,timer,errors,img,css,script}).

page_info(URL) ->
  inets:start(),
  case httpc:request(URL) of
    {ok,{_,Headers,Body}} ->
      got_page_info(URL,content_length(Headers),Body);
    {error,Reason} ->
      {error,Reason}
  end.

got_page_info(URLpassed, PageSize,Body) ->
  %getting the parsed version of website
  Tree = mochiweb_html:parse(Body),

  %particular files being listed and removing duplicates
  Imgs = rDup(mochiweb_xpath:execute("//img/@src",Tree)),
  %css does not work, do not know why
  %Css = rDup(mochiweb_xpath:execute("//link[@rel=’stylesheet’]/@href",Tree)),
  Scripts = rDup(mochiweb_xpath:execute("//script/@src",Tree)),

  %preapring URL
  URL = get_url_context(URLpassed),
      spawn_workers(URL,img,lists:map(fun  binary_to_list/1,Imgs)),
  spawn_workers(URL,script,lists:map(fun  binary_to_list/1,Scripts)),
  %Starts a timer which will send the message Msg to Dest after Time milliseconds.
  TRef = erlang:send_after(10000,self(),timeout),
  State = #state{page=PageSize,
    timer=TRef,
    errors=[],
    img=0,
    css=0,
    script=0},

  %number of elements -> so number of responses we should wait for
  wait_for_responses(State,length(Imgs)  + length(Scripts)),
  {ok}.

content_length(Headers) ->
  %proplists:get_value(Key,List,Default)
  %returns the length of the content
  list_to_integer(proplists:get_value("content-length",Headers,"0")).

%function that removes dulpicate
rDup(L) ->
  sets:to_list(sets:from_list(L)).

%spawn workers for every URl, who send back info about components -> getinfo
spawn_workers(URLctx,Type,URLs) ->
  lists:foreach(fun (Url) -> spawn( fun () ->
                                    self() ! {component, Type,Url,get_info(URLctx,Url)}
                                    end)
              end, URLs).

get_url_context(URL) ->
  {ok,{http,_,Root,_Port,Path,_Query}} = http_uri:parse(URL),
  Ctx = string:sub_string(Path,1, string:rstr(Path,"/")),
  {"http://"++Root,Ctx}. %% gib my url with context

get_info(URlctx,Url) ->
  FullURL = full_url(URlctx,Url),
  case httpc:request(head,{FullURL,[]},[],[]) of
    {ok, {_,Headers,_Body}} ->
      {ok,content_length(Headers)};
    {error,Reason} ->
      {error,Reason}
  end.


%FULL URL FUNCTIONS
%% abs url inside the same server ej: /img/image.png
full_url({Root,_Context},ComponentUrl=[$/|_]) ->
  Root ++ ComponentUrl;
%% full url ej: http://other.com/img.png
full_url({_Root,_Context},ComponentUrl="http://"++_) ->
  ComponentUrl;
% everything else is considerer a relative path.. obviously its wrong (../img)
full_url({Root,Context},ComponentUrl) ->
  Root ++ Context ++ "/" ++ ComponentUrl.

%collect infos recieved from wait_for_resposnses and add them to proper field of State
collect_info(State = #state{css=Css},css,_URL,{ok,Info}) ->
         State#state{css = Css + Info};
collect_info(State = #state{img=Img},img,_URL,{ok,Info}) ->
         State#state{img = Img + Info};
collect_info(State = #state{script=Script},script,_URL,{ok,Info}) ->
         State#state{script = Script + Info};
collect_info(State = #state{errors=Errors},_Type,URL,{error,Reason}) ->
         State#state{errors=[{URL,Reason}|Errors]}.

%messages from workers
wait_for_responses(State,0) ->
    finalize(State,0);

wait_for_responses(State,Counter) ->
    receive
      {component,Type,URL,Info} ->
          wait_for_responses(collect_info(State,Type,URL,Info),Counter - 1);
      timeout -> finalize(State,Counter)
    end.

%prepares variables for printing
 finalize(State,Left) ->
  PageSize =  State#state.page,
  ImgSize =  State#state.img,
  CssSize =  State#state.css, %maybe one day will work
  ScriptSize =  State#state.script,
  Errors =  State#state.errors,
  TRef =  State#state.timer,
  erlang:cancel_timer(TRef),
  printing(PageSize,ImgSize,CssSize,ScriptSize).

printing(PageSize,ImgSize,CssSize,ScriptSize)->
  io:format("html size: ~.2fkb~n",[PageSize/1024]),
  io:format("images size: ~.2fkb~n",[ImgSize/1024]),
  io:format("script size: ~.2fkb~n",[ScriptSize/1024]),
 % io:format("stylesheet size: ~.2fkb~n",[CssSize/1024]),
  {ok}.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the function:

```
spawn_workers(URLctx,Type,URLs) ->
  lists:foreach(fun (Url) -> spawn( fun () ->
                                    self() ! {component, Type,Url,get_info(URLctx,Url)}
                                    end)
              end, URLs).
```

self() is evaluated in the spawned process so it sends the response to itself. Assign self to a variable prior to spawn the process:

```
spawn_workers(URLctx,Type,URLs) ->
  Pid = self(),
  lists:foreach(fun (Url) -> spawn( fun () ->
                                    Pid ! {component, Type,Url,get_info(URLctx,Url)}
                                    end)
              end, URLs).
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of showing, where the error is, I'll show you, how to debug it using `dbg`, which is Erlang debugger. Start it with those commands:

```
dbg:tracer(). #start the process
dbg:p(all, c). #match all calls in patterns given later
ShowReturnedResults = [{'_', [], [{return_trace}]}] #find this magic in the docs
dbg:tpl(test, get_info, '_', ShowReturnedResults).
test:page_info("http://www.lambdadays.org").
```

This will show you, that `get_info/2` was called for every picture and returned some result.
So the problem must be with collecting results, lets check `wait_for_responses/2`:

```
dbg:stop_clear(). #clears all traces
dbg:tracer().
dbg:p(all, c).
ShowReturnedResults = [{'_', [], [{return_trace}]}] #find this magic in the docs
dbg:tpl(test, wait_for_responses, '_', ShowReturnedResults).
test:page_info("http://www.lambdadays.org").
```

Oops. It gets called only once. This means, it hit the timeout. Lets look at the messages sent during this call. Because `io:format` sends lots of messages, lets spawn the function in another process.

```
Pid = spawn(fun() -> test:page_info("http://www.lambdadays.org") end),
dbg:p(Pid, [sos, m]). #print all messages, sent and received by this process and processes, that it spawned.
```

You should get many messages, but we are interested only in the returned tuples: `{component,img...}`, so you can find something like this:

```
(<0.200.0>) <0.200.0> ! {component,img,
                               "/static/upload/media/1407924850920422agh.png",
                               {ok,189930}}
(<0.200.0>) << {component,img,"/static/upload/media/1407924850920422agh.png",
                      {ok,189930}}
(<0.199.0>) <0.199.0> ! {component,img,
                               "/static/upload/media/1407659467205755logo_glowna.png",
                               {ok,6424}}
(<0.199.0>) << {component,img,
                      "/static/upload/media/1407659467205755logo_glowna.png",
                      {ok,6424}}
```

You can read this as:

- process 0.200.0 sends to process 0.200.0 the result
- process 0.200.0 receives this result to its mailbox
- process 0.199.0 sends message to itself and receives it.

But why do they send it to themselves?

```
%spawn workers for every URl, who send back info about components -> getinfo
spawn_workers(URLctx,Type,URLs) ->
  lists:foreach(fun (Url) -> spawn( fun () ->
                                self() ! {component, Type,Url,get_info(URLctx,Url)}
                                end)
              end, URLs).
```

The inner `fun` is evaluated in the context of newly spawned process, so the process sends messages to itself, instead of parent. You have to evaluate `self()` in the context o parent and pass it down in a variable.

```
%spawn workers for every URl, who send back info about components -> getinfo
spawn_workers(URLctx,Type,URLs) ->
  Parent = self(),
  lists:foreach(fun (Url) -> spawn( fun () ->
                                Parent ! {component, Type,Url,get_info(URLctx,Url)}
                                end)
              end, URLs).
```

[dbg documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/dbg.html)

Comment: I used the debugger, and followed step by step the execution: debugger:start(), put a break point in page_info/1 and start test:page_info(Url). I also removed the timeout to have no interference with debugger. Not smart but really simple, its why I didn't think to mention it :o)